# C++ - Why does this have a strong exception guarantee?

Tags: c++

In The C++ Programming Language (4th edition), Stroustrup shows the following snippet when discussing exceptions (corrected version taken from [this errata](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th_printing3.html)):

```
template<typename T, typename A>
void vector<T,A>::reserve(size_type newalloc)   // flawed first attempt
{
    if (newalloc<=capacity()) return;           // never decrease allocation
    vector<T,A> v(newalloc);                    // make a vector with the new size
    copy(vb.elem,vb.elem+size(),v.begin());     // copy elements
    vb.space = size();
    swap(*this,v);                          // install new value 
} // implicitly release old value
```

He also says that "this has the nice property of providing the strong guarantee". However, a couple of pages before he mentioned that `std::copy` doesn't provide a strong exception guarantee. Is this a mistake, or am I missing something?

Comment: Strong exception guarantee means that if it throws nothing changes. It doesn't mean it can't throw at all. That is the no exception guarantee. Until `swap` happens `this` is unchanged.

Comment: Duh, you're right. I hadn't realized that `v` isn't a member of `this`, thus if `std::copy` fails only `v` is altered. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [François](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7359094/fran%C3%A7ois-andrieux) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62239627/c-why-does-this-have-a-strong-exception-guarantee#comment110076153_62239627), `std::copy` is changing `v`, which isn't a member of `this`. Therefore, if it fails, `this` is unaltered.

Answer (score 1):

A strong exception guarantee can be achieved for a function even if some operations it performs don't provide that guarantee.

```
copy(vb.elem,vb.elem+size(),v.begin());
```

Although `copy()` does not provide a strong guarantee, it only modifies elements of `v` but leaves `v` in state in which it can be safely destroyed (i.e. its constructor can clean up).   This is a weaker guarantee.   However, if an exception is thrown, `v` and all objects is has allocated will be destroyed by `vector`s destructor before control returns to the caller of `reserve()`, and the net effect is as if they never existed.   For the caller of `reserve()` that gives a strong guarantee.

All of the other operations in the function give either a strong guarantee or (since C++11) a `nothrow` guarantee.   Before C++11, `size()` and `capacity()` did not provide a `nothrow` guarantee, but are both `const` methods that were easily implemented as nonthrowing - part of the case for making them `nothrow` in C++11.   `std::swap()` has always been specified as nonthrowing, and was qualified `nothrow` in C++11.